# Why elements can be pushed to array but don't save properly in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that have an array property that isn't in the schema. When I try to update this property pushing an element, the document gets updated in my node app : I can see the object has the array modified, but when the document saves, the array remains as it is and other properties are updated. You will understand well while reading the code.

```
User.findOne({email: req.user.email})
        .then(user=>{
            if(user.get("posts")){
                let posts = user.get("posts");
                posts.push("word");
                user.set("posts", posts);
                //the problem is here
                //`posts` is reassigned properly to `posts` with pushed value but it can't be saved with this changement.
            }else{
                //this is when the "posts" property doesn't exist in document so it just gets added well=>no problem
                user.set("posts", "word")
            }
            //if you have `user.set("a","b")` the document gets this field added and `posts` doesn't get updated
            //if the document has property "c" set to "d" and you have `user.set("c", "h")` the "c" property gets updated properly
            user.save();
            res.send(user);
            //you can see here that the object has been successfully updated but in mongodb you cannot see the `posts`updated
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            if(err)throw err;
        });
```

here is the schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: ObjectId, auto: true},
    username: {type: String, required: true, max:18},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true, min:5},
    date_of_registration: {type: Date, required: true}
}, { strict: false });
```

I'm sorry if there was some repetitions in the code.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: What is the point of this? Why are you trying to avoid the entire idea of the schema and add randomly properties via `set`? Schema defines what mongoose can work with and what it should monitor for changes and trigger events on. What you are doing is against the entire idea of the Schema.

Comment: So if I want to add a new field, I'll have to go bacj to my schema and add it.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Your schema is your blueprint. It tells mongoose what fields you need and what it needs to keep track on, file middleware on  etc.